# HealthKit/Swift syntax to extract HKCategoryValueAppleStandHour (an enum Int)?

Tags: swift, syntax, enums, healthkit

According to Apple Documentation here: [HKActivitySummary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkactivitysummary) - 
an HKActivitySummary contains EIGHT data elements (6 vars, 1 enum & 1 function). The enum has two values (idle & stood), described here: [HKCategoryValueAppleStandHour](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategoryvalueapplestandhour)

I can successfully retrieve the 6 vars and the function with the following code - BUT I can't "see/acess" the enum of of the HKCategoryValueAppleStandHour.

```
    private func getActivitySummary() {

    let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery.init(predicate: nil)
        { (query, summaries, error) in
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            for summary in summaries! {
                // print(summary)
                let dateComponents = summary.dateComponents(for: calendar)
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

                let date = dateComponents.date

                print("Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)), Active Energy Burned: \(summary.activeEnergyBurned), Active Energy Burned Goal: \(summary.activeEnergyBurnedGoal)")
                print("Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)), Exercise Time: \(summary.appleExerciseTime), Exercise Goal: \(summary.appleExerciseTimeGoal)")
                print("Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)), Stand Hours: \(summary.appleStandHours), Stand Hours Goal: \(summary.appleStandHoursGoal)")
                print("----------------")
            }
        }
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

The above code returns:

[image: Print Output]

So I can't figure out the syntax for retrieving the "enum HKCategoryValueAppleStandHour : Int" item/property that is also supposed to be in the sample data (as per Apple Documentation above). This should contain the "idle" or "stood" flags for each hour of the day in the ActivitySummary sample.

Can anyone help me figure out the syntax for retrieving that "enum" with the AppleStandHour (idle/stood) values..?

Thanks!

Gerard